# Необходимо менять изображение у спрайта до появление в camera

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Такой вопрос, необходимо менять изображение у спрайта в тот момент ,когда объект rectangel не в фокусе у камеры.

```
camera.setToOrtho(false, Drop.WIDTH, Drop.HEIGHT);
    camera.update();
```

Объясняю:

```
**OrthographicCamera camera;** //камера
 final static int MAX_SPRITES = 24; //спрайты с изображением

Sprite bucketImage, background, r1, r2, r5, r10, r20, r50, r100, r200, r500, k1, k2, k5, k10,
        k20, k50, old100, old500, old1000, old5000, old10000, old20000, old50000, old100000,
        old200000;

Sprite[] arraySprites;
```

Для облегчения создания дождевых капель есть метод, называемый spawnRaindrop (), который создает новый прямоугольник, устанавливает его в случайное положение на верхнем краю экрана и добавляет его в массив каплями дождя.

```
   private void spawnRaindrop() {
    raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, (Drop.WIDTH) - 100);//800 -100
    raindrop.y = Drop.WIDTH + 100; //т.е 800 +100,что бы объект изменял спрайт вне камеры

    raindrop.width = 100;
    raindrop.height = 100;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}
```

Меняю спрайты в таймере так:

```
    public void timerSpriteChange() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            index = ((int) ((Math.random() * MAX_SPRITES)));

        }
    }, 1, 5);

}
```

делаю все в таймере,т.к не знаю как реализовать с камерой...

и сам вызов метода

```
 if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) {

            spawnRaindrop();

        }
```